# Format nullable DateTime in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to fetch only date part from a `DateTime` object which is nullable. I tried this thing

```
string dueDate = siteRow.DueDate.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

But it throws error:

> Error  CS1501  No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

In above `siteRow.DueDate` is a DateTime object.
I am not able to figure out the correct syntax.
Please help me out in this.

Comment: You need to check if it has a value, decide what to do when it doesn't, and then when it does you can call this on the _value_. What should `dueDate` be when there isn't a value?

Comment: You're calling [`Nullable<T>.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=net-5.0), which doesn't take any parameters. If you're sure that `siteRow.DueDate` is not null, you can do `siteRow.DueDate.Value.ToString(...)`. If you're not sure, you can do `siteRow.DueDate?.ToString(...)`,  which will result in `null` if `siteRow.DueDate` is `null`

Comment: Or you can do something like `string dueDate = siteRow.DueDate.HasValue ? siteRow.DueDate.Value.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) : "No due date";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is the generic wrapper that wraps the T type

It has 2 properties: Value and HasValue. Value is the value of the wrapped object and HasValue is a boolean that indicates if there is a value to obtain in the Value property. If HasValue is true, then Value will not be the default(usually null or empty struct). If HasValue is false, then Value will be default.

So to access the DateTime's ToString method you need to call `DueDate.Value.ToString`

would be

```
var dueDate = siteRow.DueDate.HasValue ? siteRow.DueDate.Value.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) : null
```

or using the abbreviated syntax

```
var dueDate = siteRow.DueDate?.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: But how this syntax would give me only date part of DateTime?

Comment: by pointing you at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_ not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Object_ToString